# XML Deserializer issues with PortableRest and tvdb.com API response

Tags: c#, xml, datacontractserializer

I just tried to consume the response of a REST api call from tvdb.com calling this url: http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?&seriesname=Homeland which gives me this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Data>
  <Series>
    <seriesid>247897</seriesid>
    <SeriesName>Homeland</SeriesName>
  </Series>
  <Series>
    <seriesid>84450</seriesid>
    <SeriesName>Homeland Security USA</SeriesName>
  </Series>
</Data>
```

I wanted to use the PortableRest library which has a generic async method to call the url and return an object of my classes. Under the hood PortableRest uses the **DataContractSerializer** which somehow has problems deserializing this XML properly to my object. I believe I missed some attributes, anyone an idea? This is what results...looking strange. The Content property comes from the async result.

[image: The problem]

These are my classes:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Data
{
        [DataMember]
        public IEnumerable<Series> Series { get; set; } 
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Series
{
    [DataMember(Name = "SeriesName")]
    public string SeriesName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "seriesid")]
    public string SeriesId { get; set; }
}

var data = await restClient.SendAsync<Data>(request);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your `Series` list is in one-level format rather than two-level format, but `DataContractSerializer` does not support one-level formatting for lists.  Instead, it only supports two-level formats like this:

```
<Data xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Series>
        <Series>
            <seriesid>247897</seriesid>
            <SeriesName>Homeland</SeriesName>
        </Series>
        <Series>
            ...
        </Series>
    </Series>
</Data>
```

Thus you need to deserialize the XML using the following classes:

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name="Data", Namespace="")]
public class SeriesList : List<Series>
{
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Series
{
    [DataMember(Name = "seriesid", Order=0)]
    public string SeriesId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "SeriesName", Order=1)]
    public string SeriesName { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like:

```
var list = await restClient.SendAsync<SeriesList>(request);
var data = new Data { Series = list.ToList() };
```

By the way, note the use of the [`DataMemberAttribute.Order`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.order%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.  Data contracts are [sensitive to order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) thus it is necessary to inform the serializer the order in which child XML elements will appear.